# Show $\{\emptyset,\{0,1,2\},\{0\},\{1,2\}\}$ a topology on the set $\{0,1,2\}$?

Tags: general-topology

I have a set $$X=\{0,1,2\}$$
and I know that $$\tau=\{\emptyset,X,\{0\},\{1,2\}\}$$
is a topology on the set X.

I know the axioms required to show it is a topology.

$\emptyset$ and X are both in $\tau$ so the first axiom is satisfied. This is clear.

The second axiom says that the intersection of any finite members of $\tau$ is in $\tau$. 
The third axiom says that the union of any collection of elements of $\tau$ is in $\tau$.

I can not clearly see how the second and third properties come into play, so how do I directly find the unions and intersections involved with the given example?

Comment: Just directly verify them. It's not hard to find the intersections and unions involved.

Comment: What is $\phi$? If you mean the empty set, that's $\emptyset$, obtained by `\emptyset`.

Comment: @celtschk thanks for the tip

Comment: The line that says "$\phi $ and $\tau$ are both in $\tau$ should be "$\emptyset$ and $X$ are both in $\tau$"

Comment: Maybe it helps you to notice that since $\tau$ is a finite sets, any intersections of its members are finite intersections. Same for unions.

Comment: @celtschik is $\{1,2\}$ a union or intersection in $\tau$?

Comment: @Aljabra: Do you know what an union/an intersection is? (PS: If you misspell my user name, I'll not get notified; just type the first few letters and use the tab key to get the correct user name)

Comment: @celtschk I know what an union and intersection is. (thanks for the tip)

Comment: So where is your problem in calculating the unions and intersections of the sets in $\tau$?

Comment: @celtschk I worked it out, I am being so stupid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It suffices to construct unions and intersections of all members of $\tau$ explicitly. Since the unions and intersections of any element with $\emptyset$ and $X$ are trivial, it suffices to see that $\left\{ 0 \right\} \cap \left\{ 1,2 \right\} = \emptyset$ and $\left\{ 0 \right\} \cup \left\{ 1,2 \right\}= X$, which both lie in $\tau$.